# how to create a data structure like a tree

Tags: data-structures, raku

for my project I need to build a tree structure. I am looking for a way to grow it at the leaves. I have simplified my failed attempt by using a listy structure:

```
my $root = a => (b => (c=> Nil));
my $here := $root;
while $here.value ~~ Pair {
  $here := $here.value;
}
$here = d => Nil;
```

which does not work, because I cannot change Nil, of course.
    Cannot assign to an immutable value
How can I make this work?

Thanks,
Theo van den Heuvel

Comment: Have you considered using hashes?  or is the order important?

Comment: Yes I have, Elizabeth. And I am. At some point I have to change a value somewhere in that hash by a new bit of structure. Hence my question.

Comment: Well if the project is to make a Tree I'd probably go with some kind of `Node` Role that can have 2 sub nodes. Then I'd include the functionality of adding new `Node`s as an object method.

Comment: In my attempt to minimize the problem, I have evidently made it harder. It appears, you cannot alter the value of a Pair. Right? Normally you would change it may creating a slightly altered clone. Using hashes as building blocks makes it much easier, because you can alter, insert and delete pairs as a whole.

Comment: If you really need `Nil` could you stick it inside a variable?

Comment: @Christopher, Nil is irrelevant to the problem here, it just denotes the end of a sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error message you get *"Cannot assign to an immutable value"* is because the value is not a [container](https://docs.perl6.org/language/containers). Here is an example where I make the leaf node a container:

```
my $root = a => (b => (my $ = (c => Nil)));
my $here := $root;
while $here.value ~~ Pair {
  $here := $here.value;
}
$here = d => Nil;
```

Now, there is no error message.

Comment: thanks, Håkon. On the basis of this reply and @Elizabeth, I am going to pick hashes as nodes. and add keys rather than try to change values.

Comment: @TheovandenHeuvel Regardless of what you are choosing to do with your project, this answer best answers your basic question. Please accept it as the correct answer so that anyone in the future that makes the same mistake will easily find this answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are using [binding](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#index-entry-Binding_operator), not assignment for `$here`

```
my $root = a => (b => (c=> Nil));
my $here = $root;
while $here.value ~~ Pair {
  $here = $here.value;
}
$here = d => Nil;
```

When you use bind, the left and the right-hand side are the same object. And once they are the same object, well, they can't change (if the bound object is immutable, that is). They're immutable:

```
my $bound := 3; $bound = 'þorn'; say $bound; 
# OUTPUT: «Cannot assign to an immutable value␤»
```

`3` above is immutable, so you can't assign to it. In the code you have provided, you could change the value by rebinding until you arrived to an immutable value, the last `Pair`, which explains the message.

Just use ordinary assignment and you're good to go. If what you want is to keep the original value of `$root` somewhere, just do this and use `$root` to do the tree navigation

```
my $root = a => (b => (c=> Nil));
my $here = $root;
while $root.value ~~ Pair {
  $root = $root.value;
}
$here = d => Nil;
say $here;
say $root;
```

`$here` will still be equal to the original root, and `$root` will have navigated to the last branch and leaf.

Comment: indeed. No error message. But sadly  $root is unchanged.

Comment: So that is why you wanted to use binding... Just use `$root` from the beginning. I'll edit it for that.

Comment: "When you use bind, the left and the right-hand side are the same object. And once they are the same object, well, they can't change. They're immutable". Well, if the bound object is immutable then it's still immutable after binding. But you can still just bind to another instead that isn't. You may well know that anyway, but I thought it best to comment in case anyone misunderstands what you've written.

Comment: @raiph Changed. Hope it's better now. Thanks.

Comment: thanks. I guess I was thinking "reference" in the back of my head. NB the last assignment should be to `$root` instead of $here.

Comment: Sorry, too quick there. (but too late to retract). Hmm. This is not what I wanted. It does not change the sequence. II was hoping to change it into `a => ( b => (c=> (d=>Nil)))`

Comment: @jjmerelo Consider `my $a := 42`. Now consider your wording: "once they are the same object" (they now are) "they" (which must mean `$a` and `42` right?) "can't change" (but `$a` *can* change) "(if the bound object is immutable)" `42` is indeed immutable. Your edit didn't address the issue I was trying to raise. Btw, would you be comfortable with me editing your answers if that seems workable rather than making comments like these every time? I'm game if you're OK with me doing that. (I also don't mind sticking with comments if you would prefer that. Or anything else. In summary, I'm game. :))

Comment: @raiph by all means. Edit all you want.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of valuable input from @Elizabeth, @Håkon and @jjmerelo I have created an example tree implementation.

```
my @paths = <<aap-noot-mies aap-noot-hut aap-juf tuin>>;

my %root;
for @paths -> $fn {
  my @path = $fn.split: '-';
  add-to-tree(@path);
}

print_tree(0, %root);

sub add-to-tree(@path) {
  my %tmp := %root;
  for @path -> $step {
    unless %tmp{$step}:exists {
      my %newtmp;
      %tmp{$step} = %newtmp;
    }
    %tmp := %tmp{$step};
  }
}

sub print_tree($ind, %from) {
  my $margin = ' ' x $ind;
  if %from {
    for %from.kv -> $k, $v {
      say "$margin$k:";
      print_tree($ind + 1, %$v);
    }
  } else {
    say "$margin.";
  }
}
```